# Intersections of fractal sets with connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, fractals

Let $\beta  \geq \alpha  > 0$. Let $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a measurable set with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$. Must there exist a closed connected set $B$ with Hausdorff dimension $\leq \beta$ such that $A\cap B$ has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$? This seems like it should hold with $ \beta  = \max\{\alpha ,1\}$, via some sort of ``space filling curve" type construction. I don't see a simple proof or a reference, however, and would be interested in either.

I am also interested in how regular we can take $B$ to be. For example, can we require that $B$ be the image of a curve? How about a simple curve?

Comment: Related to your second paragraph: [Analyst's TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyst's_traveling_salesman_theorem).

Comment: If $A$ is compact, then you can do this. Cover it efficiently with finitely many dyadic cubes, connect the cubes by line segments. Then do the same within each cube, and repeat the process indefinitely. The intersection of nested compact connected sets is compact and connected. $\Box$ Now, I can't remember if it's true that every $A$ has a compact subset of the same Hausdorff dimension...